# How to enable SSL with online WLST script?

Tags: ssl, weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I try to enable WebLogic domain wide administrator port with online WLST script.

```
import os

# Deployment Information 
domainname = os.environ.get('DOMAIN_NAME', 'base_domain')
admin_name = os.environ.get('ADMIN_NAME', 'AdminServer')
domainhome = os.environ.get('DOMAIN_HOME', '/u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/' + domainname)
ssl_port = os.environ.get('SSL_PORT', '7999')
admin_port = os.environ.get('SSL_ADMIN_PORT', '8888')

print('admin_name  : [%s]' % admin_name);

# Read Domain in Offline Mode
# ===========================

connect(username,password,server_url)
edit()


print ""
print "================== SSL configuration ==================="
startEdit()

# Configure SSL
#===================
cd('/Servers/' + admin_name)
set('KeyStores', 'CustomIdentityAndJavaStandardTrust')
set('CustomIdentityKeyStoreFileName', '/u01/oracle/certificates/keystore')
set('CustomIdentityKeyStorePassPhraseEncrypted', encrypt('weblogic1'))
set('CustomIdentityKeyStoreType', 'jks')

cd('SSL/' + admin_name)
set('Enabled', 'True')
set('ListenPort', int(ssl_port))
set('ServerPrivateKeyAlias', key_alias)
set('ServerPrivateKeyPassPhraseEncrypted', encrypt('weblogic1'))
set('TwoWaySSLEnabled', 'true')

print("Set CustomIdentityAndJavaStandardTrust @ [%s]" % "/u01/oracle/certificates/keystore")
print("Key alias: [%s]" % key_alias)
print("Enabled SSL listen port @ [%s]" % ssl_port)
print("Enabled two-way SSL authentication")

# Enable administration port
# ===========================
cd ('/')
set('AdministrationPortEnabled', 'true')
set('AdministrationPort', int(admin_port))

print("Enabled administration port @ [%s]" % admin_port)

# Save, activate and exit
# ==========================
print ""
save()
activate()
exit()
```

However, the script throws following error

```
<Jun 13, 2018 7:26:41,805 AM GMT> <Warning> <RMI> <BEA-080005> <An exception was
 generated by the RMI server: Remote call rejected due to wrong channel usage
 java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has a
dministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
 Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.r
jvm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-50326164812424
17496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', serve
rRef:594523856.
java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has ad
ministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.rj
vm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-503261648124241
7496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', server
Ref:594523856
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.ensureAdministratorUsesAdminChan
nel(BasicServerRef.java:433)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.checkPriviledges(BasicServerRef.
java:1089)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:378
)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:108
1)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.dispatchRequest(RJVMImpl.java:1405)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jun 13, 2018 7:26:41,817 AM GMT> <Warning> <RMI> <BEA-080005> <An exception was
 generated by the RMI server: Remote call rejected due to wrong channel usage
 java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has a
dministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
 Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.r
jvm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-50326164812424
17496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', serve
rRef:594523856.
java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has ad
ministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.rj
vm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-503261648124241
7496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', server
Ref:594523856
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.ensureAdministratorUsesAdminChan
nel(BasicServerRef.java:433)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.checkPriviledges(BasicServerRef.
java:1089)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:378
)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:108
1)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.dispatchRequest(RJVMImpl.java:1405)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jun 13, 2018 7:26:41,850 AM GMT> <Warning> <RMI> <BEA-080005> <An exception was
 generated by the RMI server: Remote call rejected due to wrong channel usage
 java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has a
dministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
 Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.r
jvm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-50326164812424
17496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', serve
rRef:594523856.
java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has ad
ministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.rj
vm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-503261648124241
7496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', server
Ref:594523856
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.ensureAdministratorUsesAdminChan
nel(BasicServerRef.java:433)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.checkPriviledges(BasicServerRef.
java:1089)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:378
)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:108
1)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.dispatchRequest(RJVMImpl.java:1405)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jun 13, 2018 7:26:41,852 AM GMT> <Warning> <RMI> <BEA-080005> <An exception was
 generated by the RMI server: Remote call rejected due to wrong channel usage
 java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has a
dministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
 Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.r
jvm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-50326164812424
17496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', serve
rRef:594523856.
java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has ad
ministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.rj
vm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-503261648124241
7496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', server
Ref:594523856
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.ensureAdministratorUsesAdminChan
nel(BasicServerRef.java:433)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.checkPriviledges(BasicServerRef.
java:1089)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:378
)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:108
1)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.dispatchRequest(RJVMImpl.java:1405)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jun 13, 2018 7:26:41,863 AM GMT> <Warning> <RMI> <BEA-080005> <An exception was
 generated by the RMI server: Remote call rejected due to wrong channel usage
 java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has a
dministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
 Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.r
jvm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-50326164812424
17496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', serve
rRef:594523856.
java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has ad
ministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.rj
vm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-503261648124241
7496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', server
Ref:594523856
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.ensureAdministratorUsesAdminChan
nel(BasicServerRef.java:433)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.checkPriviledges(BasicServerRef.
java:1089)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:378
)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:108
1)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.dispatchRequest(RJVMImpl.java:1405)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jun 13, 2018 7:26:41,868 AM GMT> <Warning> <RMI> <BEA-080005> <An exception was
 generated by the RMI server: Remote call rejected due to wrong channel usage
 java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has a
dministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
 Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.r
jvm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-50326164812424
17496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', serve
rRef:594523856.
java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has ad
ministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.rj
vm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-503261648124241
7496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', server
Ref:594523856
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.ensureAdministratorUsesAdminChan
nel(BasicServerRef.java:433)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.checkPriviledges(BasicServerRef.
java:1089)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:378
)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:108
1)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.dispatchRequest(RJVMImpl.java:1405)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
"
You will have to re-connect to the server due to some changes" "
you have made."
Disconnected from weblogic server: admin
<Jun 13, 2018 7:26:41,878 AM GMT> <Warning> <RMI> <BEA-080005> <An exception was
 generated by the RMI server: Remote call rejected due to wrong channel usage
 java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has a
dministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
 Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.r
jvm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-50326164812424
17496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', serve
rRef:326931496.
java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has ad
ministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.rj
vm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-503261648124241
7496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', server
Ref:326931496
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.ensureAdministratorUsesAdminChan
nel(BasicServerRef.java:433)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.checkPriviledges(BasicServerRef.
java:1089)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:378
)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:108
1)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.dispatchRequest(RJVMImpl.java:1405)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Jun 13, 2018 7:26:41,881 AM GMT> <Warning> <RMI> <BEA-080005> <An exception was
 generated by the RMI server: Remote call rejected due to wrong channel usage
 java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has a
dministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
 Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.r
jvm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-50326164812424
17496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', serve
rRef:594523856.
java.lang.SecurityException: User 'principals=[weblogic, Administrators]' has ad
ministration role. All tasks by adminstrators must go through an Administration
Port. Channel:Default[t3][1]:t3(t3):127.0.0.1:7001:null:-1, endpoint:weblogic.rj
vm.RJVMImpl@50ad6c43 - JVMID: '2801878478613847958C:172.17.0.2R:-503261648124241
7496S:172.17.0.2:kkv:admin' connect time: 'Wed Jun 13 07:26:37 GMT 2018', server
Ref:594523856
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.ensureAdministratorUsesAdminChan
nel(BasicServerRef.java:433)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.checkPriviledges(BasicServerRef.
java:1089)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:378
)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.dispatch(BasicServerRef.java:108
1)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl.dispatchRequest(RJVMImpl.java:1405)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>


Exiting WebLogic Scripting Tool.


Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell
Type help() for help on available commands

admin_name  : [admin]
Connecting to t3s://localhost:8881 with userid weblogic ...
<Jun 13, 2018 7:26:50 AM GMT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling the Cryp
toJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable
this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true.
>
<Jun 13, 2018 7:26:50 AM GMT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the defau
lt Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG128 to HMACDRBG. To disable
 this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true.>
<Jun 13, 2018 7:26:50 AM GMT> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090909> <Using the configur
ed custom SSL Hostname Verifier implementation: weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHo
stnameVerifier$NullHostnameVerifier.>
Successfully connected to Admin Server "admin" that belongs to domain "kkv".
Location changed to edit tree.
This is a writable tree with DomainMBean as the root.
To make changes you will need to start an edit session via startEdit().
For more help, use help('edit').
```

Regardless of the error, the port seems to be enabled. But how could I avoid this error, i.e. still allow the current WLST edit session to use non secure channel after enabling administration port in the current edit session, and activate the changes and exit cleanly without the error message?

Comment: What port does server_url point to ? As long as it points to the non-ssl port, it should work.